# Visual Studio: Draw font from assets folder

Tags: visual-studio

quick question:

```
    Typeface font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(this.Assets, "fonts/Letter_Gothic_Std_Bold.ttf");

    TextView username = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.username);

    username.SetTypeface(font, TypefaceStyle.Bold);
```

This throws an exeption. It basically says it couldn't find my font.

The fond however, lies in within the "Assets" folder which lies in the project folder.

How do I make the call right? I tried "assets/" and all that.. didnt work :(

THANKS :)

Answer (score -1):

Okay, it was easy. When it is under assets, I dont need the "Assets/" or "fonts" infront. thanks tho!